# How I can tell if my engine was damaged, due to oil spurting out from a damaged oil filter?

Tags: engine, honda, oil-change, damage, crv

Several months ago, my oil and oil filter were changed at Sears.  Then all of a sudden my 2015 crv started making a noise. By the time I got home, oil light started flashing on and off occasionaly, not staying on though.  Next morning oil puddle on my garage floor.  Called and had it towed to dealership to see what was going on.  Sears had used a wrench to install oil filter, caused, scratches, dents and crushed oil filter.  It is believed this caused a small hole, several months later that caused oil loss.  Oil was all gone by time it got to dealership.  They changed oil and oil filter.  Had oil filter cut open.  A few filings in found in oil filter.  None found in oil that was put in and drained out, before they actually changed oil filter and oil.  Car seems to be running fine now, drove over 1,000 miles.  Is there a possibilit my engine was damaged>

Answer (score 2):

The big question here is: *Did engine damage occur?*

The answer: *Most definitely.*

When an engine is ran without oil or very low oil, lubrication suffers and metal on metal contact of engine parts can occur.

Due to this, the question then becomes: *How much damage occurred due to the negligence?*

The answer: *It is hard to tell.*

Without a complete engine teardown and full inspection, there's no way to tell how much damage occurred. Yes, some damage occurred, have no doubt about it. How much did it shorten the engine life of the vehicle? There's no way to know. More than likely only minimal damage has occurred. Better yet, you'll probably never know the difference. The difference may be the engine may last 10k miles less than it would have otherwise (and I'm just throwing numbers out there). The thing is, though, Honda's have a great reputation for longevity. If you continue to take care of your vehicle with proper maintenance, you'll most likely trade the vehicle off before you'll get to the end of your vehicle's lifespan.

The engine would be the only part which might have been affected. Since you were cognizant enough to quit running the vehicle when you noticed a problem, I'm sure only a very minor amount of damage occurred. Again, you'll probably never even notice the difference. Considering the engine now seems to be running just fine, you've most likely avoided a huge repair bill, even if it was some lousy tech's problem. Chalk it up to the tech having a bad day and don't go back there again.

Comment: If I have my oil and oil filter changed again now, after driving over 1000 miles, had the oil filter cut open and no filings, would that be a sign that the engine didn't get damaged?  Thank you

Comment: On Top Gear in one episode, they drained the oil out of an engine then started it - it ran for a surprising amount of time before it failed.

Comment: Checking for filings : sadly no, not all the damage will cause filings.

Comment: No filings in the new filter only means that nothing 'new' has broken loose. You don't mention the mileage on the engine and if you drive mostly City or Highway or what the mix is. Those will also have a impact on engine life. I am kind of surprised the dealer didn't drop the oil pan and see how much stuff had collected on the magnet which is below the oil pickup and allowed visual access to the lower half of the engine. That work could have been charged to Sears because otherwise it would not have been necessary. Out of curiosity what does your dealer say for the engine life?

Comment: Oh and for your information, when you install an oil filter you thread it on hand tight no more. So using a wrench as an automatic fail.

Comment: @RowanHawkins - Most suggest 1/4 turn past gasket (o-ring) touchdown, but yes, easily done by hand. What's amazing is even at this low level of torque on the filter, how hard it can be to take off when it's oil change time. Amazing.

Comment: Well by that time the oil that you've applied to the gasket ring has migrated someplace else and the heating and cooling of the engine and the pressure of the oil system has firmly seated the filter to the engine. Oil filters - hand on, wrench off. And destroying an oil filter taking it off is not a problem.

Comment: 40,000 miles.  Dealer says only way to be sure no engine damage is to take engine apart.  They daid, since I have drove it 1500 miles since, no sounds or issues, might have caught it in time.  Could possibly shorten life if engine.   Sears denies all responsibility.  Says anyone else coukd have changed it sibce.  I eoukd have had issues before now if due to their oil filter, since I had drove 7,000 milrs.